# longest path in a matrix

Tags: c, arrays

Given a N X N  matrix Matrix[N][N] of positive integers.  There are only three possible moves from a cell Matrix[r][c].

1. Matrix[r+1][c]
2. Matrix[r+1][c-1]
3. Matrix[r+1][c+1]

Starting from any column in row 0, return the largest sum of any of the paths up to row N-1.

my code is running nice for a single test case but for multiple test cases its giving wrong answer.
In the main function of code i am passing a two dimensional array and number of elements in array as arguments

```
int findSum(int a[][100],int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            int x=a[i][j];
            if(j==0)
            {
                a[i][j]=max(a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j+1])+x;
            }
            if(j==n-1)
            {
                a[i][j]=max(a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j-1])+x;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i][j]=max(a[i-1][j],max(a[i-1][j-1],a[i-1][j+1]))+x;
            }
        }
    }
    int maxm=a[n-1][0];
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(a[n-1][j]>maxm)
           maxm=a[n-1][j];
    }
    return maxm;
}
```

Array is taken as input from user

```
while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
               scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
        int num=findSum(a,n);
        printf("%d\n",num);
    }
```

For Input:
2
3
5 6 7
7 6 5
7 6 5
3
7 3 2
4 1 5
6 8 9
Your Output is:
20
32
the expected output should be 19 for the 2nd case

Comment: How is the array initialized? How do you call this function? Please try to create a [mcve] that replicates your problem, and it's okay if the example you show us have hard-coded values.

Comment: I also suggest you *debug* your program. With a *debugger* you can step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. If you do that (or even do some quick [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)) you should hopefully find out your problem very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if-else-if, instead of multiple if statement.

```
if(j==0)
{
     a[i][j] += max(a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j+1]);
}
else if(j==n-1)
{
     a[i][j] += max(a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j-1]);
}
else
{
     a[i][j] += max(a[i-1][j],max(a[i-1][j-1],a[i-1][j+1]));
}
```